# Replacement explorer.exe needing administrative privileges (Win10)

Tags: windows, registry

I have a tablet running Windows 10, and I need to lock it down to only run my custom executables.

My launch executable require administrative privileges to perform some functions (e.g. change system clock, start other executables, open/close serial ports) and I have enabled "Run this program as an administrator" in the executable compatibility settings. Launching the application via double-click in an explorer window or via command line, the system is able to launch its other dependent executables and functions correctly.

However, I need to get this executable to launch on log-in, and research suggests replacing the registry key linking to `explorer.exe` with my own `launch.exe` to be the simplest approach. I proved this works with `notepad.exe`, but my `launch.exe` application doesn't start... I just get a black screen.

What am I missing here to get my own executable to launch?

### Attempt Breakdown

By creating a registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell` and setting its value to `notepad.exe`, I can get notepad to start on launch.

When I change the value of the `Shell` key to `C:\Windows\notepad.exe`, this works too.

When I change the value of the `Shell` key to my custom executable, e.g. `C:\custom\launch.exe`... I get a black screen and no evidence the executable was launched as no log files from my system are generated.

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround Solution:

I was able to use Task Scheduler to launch my application with highest privileges, thus side-stepping the problem in the question above.

To disable explorer.exe as required, I replaced the `Shell` key value with a custom `do_nothing.bat` script that does (almost) nothing... and thus doesn't trigger explorer.exe. The file cannot be empty as otherwise Windows throws an error.

### do_nothing.bat:

```
rem ---DO SOMETHING TO PREVENT EXPLORER.EXE LAUNCHING---
cd \
```